# Why does my code throwing KeyError: 'epochs' when I implemented Fully Convolutional Networks by Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement FCN by TensorFlow, and I used Keras. After first epoch training , I got this error:

[image: KeyError:"epochs"]

I think it should be related to ModelCheckpoint() and model.fit(), because when I delete callbacks in model.fit(), it could finish all epochs.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

This is part of my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os
from skimage.transform import resize
from skimage.io import imsave
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras import backend as K
from keras.callbacks import *
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
import shutil

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *
from keras.regularizers import l2
from keras.layers import *
from keras.engine import Layer
from keras.applications.vgg16 import *
from keras.models import *
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import _obtain_input_shape
import tensorflow as tf
import time

K.set_image_data_format('channels_last')  # TF dimension ordering in this code

starttime = time.clock()

img_rows = 512
img_cols = 512

smooth = 1.


def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)




def FCN32():
    # https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.1/vgg16_weights_th_dim_ordering_th_kernels.h5
    inputs = Input((img_rows, img_cols, 1))
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block1_conv1')(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block1_conv2')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block1_pool')(conv1)
    # Block 2

    conv2 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block2_conv1')(pool1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block2_conv2')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block2_pool')(conv2)

    # Block 3
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv1')(pool2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv2')(conv3)
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv3')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block3_pool')(conv3)

    # Block 4

    conv4 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv1')(pool3)

    conv4 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv2')(conv4)
    conv4 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv3')(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block4_pool')(conv4)

    # Block 5

    conv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block5_conv1')(pool4)
    conv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block5_conv2')(conv5)
    conv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block5_conv3')(conv5)
    pool5 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block5_pool')(conv5)


    up1 = (Conv2D(32, (7, 7), activation='relu', padding='same'))(pool5)
    drop1 = Dropout(0.5)(up1)
    up2 = (Conv2D(32, (1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same'))(drop1)
    drop2 = Dropout(0.5)(up2)

    up3 = (Conv2D(1, (1, 1), kernel_initializer='he_normal'))(drop1)
    up4 = Conv2DTranspose(1, kernel_size=(64, 64), strides=(30, 30), use_bias=False)(up3)

    crop1 = Cropping2D(cropping=((1, 1), (1, 1)))(up4)

    model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[crop1])
    model.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.005), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=[dice_coef])

    return model

def train_and_predict():
    print('-' * 30)
    print('Loading train data...')
    print('-' * 30)
    imgs_train = np.load('train_data.npy') 
    imgs_label_train = np.load('train_label.npy')

    imgs_train = imgs_train.reshape(1000, 512, 512, 1)
    imgs_label_train = imgs_label_train.reshape(1000, 512, 512, 1)

    #    imgs_train = preprocess(imgs_train)
    ##imgs_mask_train = preprocess(imgs_mask_train)

    imgs_train = imgs_train.astype('float32')
    mean = np.mean(imgs_train)  # mean for data centering
    std = np.std(imgs_train)  # std for data normalization

    imgs_train -= mean
    imgs_train /= std

    imgs_label_train = imgs_label_train.astype('float32')
    imgs_label_train /= 255.  # scale masks to [0, 1]

    print('-' * 30)
    print('Creating and compiling model...')
    print('-' * 30)
    log_filepath = '/logs'
    model = FCN32()


    model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('fcn32_weights.{epochs:02d-{dice_coef:.2f}}.h5', monitor='val_loss',
                                       save_best_only=True)
    tb_cb = TensorBoard(log_dir=log_filepath, write_images=False, histogram_freq=1, write_graph=True)

    print('-' * 30)
    print('Fitting model...')
    print('-' * 30)

    model.fit(imgs_train, imgs_label_train, batch_size=10, epochs=10, verbose=1, shuffle=True,
              validation_split=0.02,
              callbacks=[model_checkpoint, tb_cb])

    print('-' * 30)
    print('Loading test data...')
    print('-' * 30)
    imgs_test = np.load('test_data.npy') 
    imgs_test = imgs_test.reshape(100, 512, 512, 1)


    imgs_test = imgs_test.astype('float32')
    imgs_test -= mean
    imgs_test /= std

    print('-' * 30)
    print('Loading saved weights...')
    print('-' * 30)
    model.load_weights('fcn32_weights.h5')

    print('-' * 30)
    print('Predicting masks on test data...')
    print('-' * 30)
    imgs_mask_test = model.predict(imgs_test, batch_size=10, verbose=1)

    np.save('imgs_mask_test.npy', imgs_mask_test)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    train_and_predict()

endtime = time.clock()
print("The train_and_predict running time is %g s" % (endtime - starttime))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you get the error at the end of first epoch, it may be due to your ModelCheckpoint callback: you have placed the first `}` at the wrong place!

Try

```
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('fcn32_weights.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.h5', monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True)
```